# What are the permissions on the eosio.prods accounts used for

Tags: block-producer, permissions, blocks

eosio.prods has the following permissions (see https://eosauthority.com/account/eosio.prods#keys):

`15/21 active (controls the eosio account)`

`11/21 prod.major`

`8/21 prod.minor`

these are updated at the start of each block. What are the *prod.major* and *prod.minor* permissions used for?

Answer (score 1):

Answer courtesy of Michael Yeates on Telegram https://t.me/c/1139062279/173476

> Major and minor are just lower threshold permissions which can be used
>   for anything which requires a lower threshold, they arent used in the
>   core at all.
>
> We use minor here to allow 8/21 to remove an entry from the whitelist.
>
> https://bloks.io/account/unusedaccnts#keys

Every time they need a tx executed they need to go to the BPs to get them to trigger it.

Comment: Great to see you joining stack exchange and contributing from the wealth of knowledge that we can get from people on Telegram!